# Heroku Proxy Issue with outbound HTTPS connections

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, heroku, auth0

I'm running a Java 8 Spring Boot application on a heroku free dyno. My app is a REST API which drives an single page app which is secured with Auth0 using JWT.

This runs perfectly well on other hosts (AWS etc..) but on heroku when I run the app, authenticate and the javascript client makes a call to the REST api I get the following error

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocol = https host = null
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702463+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702464+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1150) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702465+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702466+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702479+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702480+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702481+00:00 app[web.1]: at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702482+00:00 app[web.1]: at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1045) ~[na:1.8.0_161-heroku]
2018-02-14T13:48:35.702484+00:00 app[web.1]: at com.auth0.jwk.UrlJwkProvider.getJwks(UrlJwkProvider.java:58) ~[jwks-rsa-0.2.0.jar!/:na]
```

I believe this is a proxy issue. Can anyone tell me if http requests from a heroku dyno are redirected through a proxy? If so I believe I can solve the issue by adding the following flag to my JVM start up

```
-Dhttp.proxy=...
```

I'm pretty stuck with this and cannot successfully run my app on heroku without a solution. Has anyone else experienced anything similar when running on heroku?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Heroku sends your requests through it’s own router, which terminates SSL/HTTPS. So the request is in HTTP when it reaches your app.

Comment: No, this is a https request from the app on heroku to an external end point, auth0.com

Comment: I see. Then no, outbound requests are not set through a proxy